# React - how to set inline CSS for each element of map function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have an application in React where I'm trying to read in data from a JSON file. The JSON file is in the following format:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Max",
        "age": "21",
    },

    {
        "name": "Sam",
        "age": "18",
    }

    ........
]
```

I have successfully read in the right data and displayed it on my screen, like this:

```
function foo(){
    const styling = css`
        font-size: 30px;
    `;

    return(
        <div>
            {people.map((person, i) => <Format key={i} {...person} css={styling}/>)}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Although all the information correctly displays on the screen, the styling is not getting applied to each person. How could I change this?

**EDIT**

Format component:

```
function Format({name, age}){
   return (
      <div>
         <h1>{name}</h1>
         <h2>{age}</h2>
      </div>
   );
}
```

Comment: How your Format component looks like ?

Comment: Updated. Can I just style it there?

Comment: You are not using the css prop in Format component.

Comment: You using any library for CSS ? i don't think there's any prop named css by default and also you're not using the passed prop anywhere

Comment: I'm using emotion and css.

Comment: Actually, I just figured it out!!

Comment: what was the problem? @DarrelGulseth

Comment: I ended up adding css in the Format file itself, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

```
function Format({name, age, css}){
   return (
      <div css={css}>
         <h1>{name}</h1>
         <h2>{age}</h2>
      </div>
   );
}
```

you passed styled to your component but you didnt use them in your child component

and plus using idx as key is not the best practice. following article explains why. 
https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

if name is unique you can pass each items name to mapped children.